# URL is not entering after firefox browser is invoked in python by selenium

Tags: firefox, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to open Google website by selenium using python language. Here It invoking Firefox browser but unable to paste the URL , i think the version which i am using is not supported

i am using **selenium v2.35** and **Firefox 10.0**

Is these both are compatible or else please suggest me which Firefox version i have to install

I used the following code to invoke the browser

```
 from selenium import webdriver

    def Main():

        driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        url = driver.get("http://google.com")

    Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this changelog](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/py/CHANGES), Firefox version till 23 is supported by selenium 2.35.

Try updating your firefox to any version greater than 12 and less than 24. It should work as expected.